# The value of the string variable cannot be converted to an integer

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am currently working on the functionality of user liking items in the store. My goal is to allow a user to like a product and add it to the list of liked products, one user can like multiple products, and each product can be liked by multiple users. However, the problem is that when I test the request in Postman I get a 400 Bad Request with Invalid user format (I hit the 3rd if condition), even though the user has an Id of type int in his entity.

When debugging I found: userString = "saymon", and the user is logged in.

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions?

```
//Here are product and user entity
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public List<Product> LikedProducts { get; set; } = new List<Product>();
}

//And here is my endpoint in controller
[HttpPost("add-to-favorites/{productId}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> AddToFavorites(int productId)
{
    var userString = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
    var product = await _productRepository.GetProductById(productId);

    if (product == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    if (product.UserId.ToString() == userString)
    {
        return BadRequest("You cannot like your own product.");
    }

    if (!int.TryParse(userString, out int id))
    {
        return BadRequest("Invalid user ID format.");
    }

    var user = await _userRepository.GetUser(id);
    user.LikedProducts.Add(product);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: Examine the value of `userString` in a debugger and see why it's not parseable to an int. Include it in your question too.

Comment: If you included the content of the `userString` in the output it might tell you what's wrong: `return BadRequest($"'{userString}' does not comply with valid user ID format.");`

Answer (score 2):

Your `userString` is a claim value, that is most likely a string. Maybe `Eric`, maybe `7cf7f915-aa34-4399-a2cd-5a7867163c0c`. Since you did not provide us with a concrete value, we don't know whats really in it.

What we do know is, that it is not a number represented as a string. For example `"13"`.

So you need to check, if you really expect an integer value. If so, check if you are retrieving the correct claim.
If you are not expecting an integer, check which type `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` actually represents. I'd bet on `Guid`.

Comment: I'd bet `userString` is `null`.

Comment: Or that, of course. But assuming a user is logged in, that claim should be populated.

Comment: I did debugger, userString = "saymon", and the user is logged in

Comment: I agree with Marco, based on your feedback you are getting a string value (maybe the UserName) when you are clearly trying to get the Id field from the User class.  Either pull the User Id value directly or you need something to convert your username to user Ids.  But I really think you should be able to pull the Id directly.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimtypes?view=net-7.0 shows the return types of different claims.  NameIdentifier clearly returns string so either you are pulling the wrong claim or you need to examine if you really want an int or if string is actually the datatype you want.